# I get error when use android:background and item_bg.xml

Tags: android, android-listview

I try to create a selectable Listview.

Everthing is right but i get error when i use the `android:background="@drawable/item_bg"`

***drawable/item_bg.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_activated="true"
        android:color="#999999">
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="#FF00FF">
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="#b3bdff">
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:color="#000000">
    </item>

</selector>
```

***Error lines:***

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class
>
> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable-hdpi-v4/item_bg

If I deleted all item tag it work but not to be selectable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved!

- deleted all drawable files! deleted attribute what name
- android:background="@drawable/item_bg" created xml again but with
- different name!(e.g. item_bg_selector) created colors.xml define
- attibute again (android:background="@drawable...")

it's done!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new xml file (Color, gradient...)  into drawable folder and then use this file with any attribute into layout you write without extensión.

Comment: Thank you it just wrong spelling in there. It doesn't exist in my code block.